# How to animate alongside a UISearchController presentation/dismissal animation?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uisearchcontroller

I have a table view with a search bar in the `tableHeaderView`, managed by a `UISearchController`. I use the standard `UISearchController` presentation animation.

I want to animate another view with the same duration as the searchBar animation. I tried various duration values but alas they don't match perfectly at all times.

So I thought it would be great to make use of the `-[UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator animateAlongsideTransition:completion:]` API.

Unfortunately I can't find a reference of the `<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>` object. Specifically, `searchController.presentingViewController.transitionCoordinator` is `nil`.

Comment: Just in case, did you ever solve this ? I'm having a [similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35944246/animate-uisearchbar-and-uibarbuttonitem-simultaneously-with-uisearchcontroller)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem, I needed to animate other views alongside the the presentation of the `UISearchController`; After the call to present the search controller the `transitionCoordinator` becomes available and you can add code to animate your views

**Presenting:**

```
func search() {
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsController)
    // Configure search controller
    self.present(searchController, animated: true) {}

    self.transitionCoordinator?.animate(alongsideTransition: { (context) in
        // animate other views
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

I also had to animate the views while dismissing the search controller, in this case I implement the `willDismissSearchController` method of the `UISearchControllerDelegate`, the `transitionCoordinator` is not immediately available in this method but making an asynchronous call does the trick

**Dismissing:**

```
func willDismissSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        searchController.transitionCoordinator?.animate(alongsideTransition: { (context) in
            // animate views
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

This works for me from iOS 9

Comment: If you are relying on the user tapping into a search bar to automatically present the `UISearchController` then you can use the same technique in `willPresentSearchController` as @juanjo has used in `willDismissSearchController`

Comment: These delegate methods aren't called if you use `isActive = false` to dismiss.